# GDB: redirect target stdout temporarly

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, stdout

When I launch GDB the targeted process prints a lot of data so I want to redirect it to NULL until a certain point in time.

the only two methods i've found so far are:

1. run > filename
2. tty filename

the problem is i cannot find a way to restore the stdout of the inferior back to normal.

there is no "tty default", or "default tty"

Thanks,

Itay

Comment: `run | sed '1,100d'`? Or whatever number for 100 is the last number of the output you want to ignore (delete). Good luck.

Answer (score 9):

> i cannot find a way to restore the stdout of the inferior back to normal

Here is how you can do it:

```
Reading symbols from /tmp/./a.out...done.
(gdb) list main
1   #include <stdio.h>
2
3   int main() {
4     int i;
5
6     for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
7       printf("A line we don't care about: %d\n", i);
8     }
9     printf("An important line\n");
10    return 0;
11  }
(gdb) b 9
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400579: file t.c, line 9.
(gdb) run > /dev/null
Starting program: /tmp/./a.out > /dev/null

Breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:9
9     printf("An important line\n");
(gdb) call fflush(0)
$1 = 0
```

Since we are about to switch output, we want to make sure to flush any buffered data.

Next we call `open("/dev/tty", O_WRONLY)`. You can find the value of `O_WRONLY` by `grep`ping for it in `/usr/include`.

```
(gdb) shell grep WRONLY /usr/include/bits/*.h
/usr/include/bits/fcntl.h:#define O_WRONLY       01
(gdb) p open("/dev/tty", 1)
$2 = 3
```

So we now have a new file descriptor `3` that will output to the current terminal. Finally, we switch `STDOUT_FILENO` to it, like so:

```
(gdb) call dup2(3, 1)
$3 = 1
(gdb) c
Continuing.
An important line
[Inferior 1 (process 22625) exited normally]
```

Voilà: "An important line" was printed to the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on [Employed Russian's solution](/a/20864307), I have written a standalone GDB-python script which will toggle redirection to and from stdout and the active terminal (TTY). As it stands, the script is ineffective if the program output isn't redirected to begin with (`run > /dev/null`).

To activate the script, use the `source` command:

```
(gdb) b 10
Breakpoint 1 at 0x5555555547a8: file gdbtest.c, line 10.
(gdb) run > /dev/null
Starting program: /home/gdbtest > /dev/null

Breakpoint 1, main () at gdbtest.c:10
10    printf("An important line\n");
(gdb) list
5   
6     setbuf(stdout, NULL);
7     for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
8       printf("A line we don't care about: %d\n", i);
9     }
10    printf("An important line\n");
11    for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
12      printf("A line we don't care about: %d\n", i);
13    }
14    //fflush(stdout);
(gdb) source redir-stdout.py 
(gdb) redir-stdout 
Inferior PID: 20749
Redirecting stdout (fd:4) to TTY (fd:3)
(gdb) n
An important line
11    for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
(gdb) n
12      printf("A line we don't care about: %d\n", i);
(gdb) n
A line we don't care about: 0
11    for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
(gdb) redir-stdout 
Inferior PID: 20749
Redirecting TTY (fd:3) back to stdout (fd:4)
(gdb) n
12      printf("A line we don't care about: %d\n", i);
(gdb) n
11    for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
(gdb) n
12      printf("A line we don't care about: %d\n", i);
(gdb)
```

Here is the script (which I named redir-stdout.py):

```python
import gdb

class RedirectStdout(gdb.Command):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RedirectStdout, self).__init__("redir-stdout", gdb.COMMAND_USER)
        self.tty = None
        self.stdout = None
        self.redir = False
        gdb.events.exited.connect(self.exit_handler)

    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        print("Inferior PID: %s" % gdb.selected_inferior().pid)
        if(gdb.selected_inferior().pid == 0):
            raise gdb.GdbError ("Error: must have an active debuggee")

        out = gdb.execute("call fflush(0)", to_string=True)
        if(self.tty is None):
            # or just /dev/tty, as shown (the 1 means WRONLY)
            out = gdb.execute("p open(\"/dev/tty\", 1)", to_string=True)
            self.tty = out.split('=')[-1].strip()

        if(self.stdout is None):
            out = gdb.execute("p open(\"/proc/self/fd/1\", 1)", to_string=True)
            self.stdout = out.split('=')[-1].strip()

        if(not self.redir):
            print("Redirecting stdout (fd:{}) to TTY (fd:{})".format(self.stdout, self.tty))
            out = gdb.execute("call dup2({}, 1)".format(self.tty), to_string=True)
            ret = out.split('=')[-1].strip()
            #print("dup2 returns: " + ret)
            self.redir = True
        else:
            print("Redirecting TTY (fd:{}) back to stdout (fd:{})".format(self.tty, self.stdout))
            out = gdb.execute("call dup2({}, 1)".format(self.stdout), to_string=True)
            ret = out.split('=')[-1].strip()
            #print("dup2 returns: " + ret)
            self.redir = False

    def exit_handler(self, event):
        self.tty = None
        self.stdout = None
        self.redir = False

instance = RedirectStdout()

def exit_handler (event):
    print("Exit event received")
    instance.exit_handler(event)
```

Note: the script is easily sourced from your local `.gdbinit` in either the current working directory or your home directory.