# gdb: Redirect stdout without running the program

Tags: gdb

In gdb, we normally use `r > log.txt` to redirect stdout.  This also runs the program.

Is there a way to redirect stdout (only, not stdin) without actually starting the program?

My intended workflow is:

```
redirect stdout to log.txt
call func1(a, b, c) # I want the stdout output going to log.txt, without any gdb info, just stdout
```

Note that `tty` command won't work in this case (I want to redirect stdout only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My intended workflow is:

Your intended workflow will not work: you *can't* `call func1(...)` *without* first running the program.

It *appears* that what you want is (roughly):

1. `start` the program (runs to `main`).
2. `call func1(...)` with its output redirected to a file.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20864307/50617) shows how to redirect the output wherever you want at an arbitrary point in program execution.

Comment: The program doesn't have the full libc included; it's written in asm and has minimal syscalls.  So I'm not sure if the method in the linked answer will work.  Is it possible to issue the equivalent of `start > logfile` or some other way of using `r >` redirect without actually doing a full `r`?

Comment: Also:  Can you explain why you can't run some code in a program  "without first running the program."? Imagine the code I wish to call was the entrypoint.

Comment: @SRobertJames Revealing your restrictions and preconditions after an answer is provided wastes everyone's time. Can you edit the question to at least explain why a simple `(gdb) starti > /tmp/output (gdb) call func1(...)` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Thank you, that solves it.  For some reason, `start` can't be redirected, but `starti` (which I was not familiar with) can be.